# Событие click()

Tags: html, jquery

Есть несколько блоков такой структуры, но с разным контентом

```
<div class="filter-section allow-multiple-expanded expanded">
    <header>
        <span class="text">Наличие:</span>

        <button type="button" class="btn-expand"></button>
    </header>
   <div class="expand-content">

      <label class="checkbox-styled">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Y" name="arrFilter_3041_2254365807" id="arrFilter_3041_2254365807" onclick="smartFilter.click(this)"/>
        <span class="checkbox-content">
            <i class="flaticon-check14"></i>
            В наличии
        </span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Скажите пожалуйста как изменить скрипт, чтобы при нажатии на .btn-expand закрывался/открывался .expand-content именно того блока на который было нажато? (в данном случае это происходит со всеми блоками такого класса)

```
$('.btn-expand').live('click', function(event) {        
     $('.expand-content').toggle('show');
});
```

Comment: `$(this).closest(".filter-section").find(".expand-content").toggle("show");`

Comment: стоит обновить версию jQuery и заменить live на on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура не ясна, от этого, подняться к родительскому элементу `header` и найти следующий элемент с классом:

```
$('.btn-expand').live('click', function(event) {        
     $(this).closest('header').next('.expand-content').toggle('show');
});
```